# Recuperar o valor de uma props no componente filho

Tags: react

Sou iniciante com o React e estou com uma dificuldade em recuperar o valor de uma props, em um componente filho.
Tenho um componente chamado Busca, que ao clicar em um botão, eu passo via props o valor para um outro componente, que chamei de Mapa
Eu consigo recuperar o valor, mas somente dentro do método render. Como eu recupero o valor e atribuo a uma outra variável por exemplo ou state para que eu possa utilizar em algum outro método?

Busca.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Mapa from './Mapa';

class Busca extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: '',
      cep: ''
    };

    this.buscarEndereco = this.buscarEndereco.bind(this)
  }

  buscarEndereco(){
    this.setState({
      input: '',
      cep: this.state.input
    });
  }

  updateInputValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      input: evt.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <h3>Consultade endereço</h3>
      <div className="col-md-6 jumbotron">          
              <div className="form-group row">
                  <div className="col-sm-12">
                      <p><strong>Consultar</strong></p>
                  </div>
                  <label for="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">CEP</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-5">
                      <input value={this.state.input} type="text" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} className="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                      <input type="button" onClick={this.buscarEndereco} value="Buscar" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>

      <Mapa cep={this.state.cep}/>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Busca;
```

Mapa.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Mapa extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Mapa {this.props.cep}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Mapa;
```

Comment: "Eu consigo recuperar o valor, mas somente dentro do método render" - como assim ? No componente `Mapa`, `this.props.cep` irá funcionar em qualquer método

Comment: Então, acontece que eu preciso atribuir o this.props.cep a uma variavel pra fazer uma consulta na API, só que n estou sabendo como fazer

Comment: É so fazer `let minhaVar = this.props.cep;` em qualquer método da classe `Mapa`. Não estou a conseguir perceber a dificuldade.

Comment: Não cara, não funciona, pois existe o lance do ciclo de vida do componente. Quando eu digito algo e aperto o botão, o this.props.cep e atulizado, beleza. Mas eu preciso que para cada clique, eu possa recuperar fora do render, precisava passar como se fosse uma state entedeu?

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui perceber. Se o objetivo é alterar estado então tem de utilizar `this.setState` e não `props`. Acho que o melhor é exemplificar a linha de código onde está a tentar obter esse valor. Colocar exatamente como tentou e não funcionou.

Comment: Ok, vou editar o código e adiciono comentários

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir um estado no componente Mapa:

```
this.state = { cep: '' };
```

e no método `render` antes do `return` verificar se o valor do estado `cep` do componente é diferente informado por `props` se for irá atualizar o estado:

```
(this.state.cep !== this.props.cep) && this.setState({cep: this.props.cep});
```

#### Exemplo funcionando

```js
class Mapa extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cep: '' };
  }

  metodoA = _ => {
    alert(this.state.cep);
  }

  render() {
    (this.state.cep !== this.props.cep) && this.setState({cep: this.props.cep});
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Mapa {this.state.cep}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.metodoA}>Exibir Mensagem</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Busca extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: '',
      cep: ''
    };

    this.buscarEndereco = this.buscarEndereco.bind(this)
  }

  buscarEndereco(){
    this.setState({
      input: '',
      cep: this.state.input
    });
  }

  updateInputValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      input: evt.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <h3>Consultade endereço</h3>
      <div className="col-md-6 jumbotron">          
              <div className="form-group row">
                  <div className="col-sm-12">
                      <p><strong>Consultar</strong></p>
                  </div>
                  <label for="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">CEP</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-5">
                      <input value={this.state.input} type="text" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} className="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                      <input type="button" onClick={this.buscarEndereco} value="Buscar" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>

      <Mapa cep={this.state.cep}/>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Busca />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, assim que chegar em casa irei testar

Answer (score 0):

Voce tem acesso ao CEP dentro do componente que instancia o MAPA e o CEP.
Dentro do MAPA vc tem acesso ao valor do CEP tbm.

Seu problema esta em: Antes de renderizar o mapa vc precisa validar o cep, e ou chamar uma api.

No meu entendimento:
o valor do cep esta no state do container/component/view, quando este valor muda, vc deve fazer o call da api dentro deste assim que vc clica no botao.

Seu botao deve chamar a api passando o valor do cep. caso retorne o certo, passe esse valor para o mapa, caso contrario o erro.

Acredito tambem que seu codigo seja um prototipo de como tudo vai funcionar, pois, seu mapa deveria ser um componente funcional, seu CEP tambem, e somente o componente que utiliza se do CEP e do MAPA poderia ser ou nao um stateful componente.
Por vias praticas, somente o componente que seria o de VIEW deveria ser steteful ou deveria ter razao muito forte para que um simples componente possa ser um class component.